How can I re-filter queryset without N+1 problems in Django?
I have simple N+1 problem with queryset in Django.
Simple views.py code example of the problem what I'm having.
a_queryset = AA.objects.filter(user=request.user).all()
# some codes in here with a_queryset . . .
b_queryset = a_queryset.filter(id__in=[3,4,5])  # re-filtered
# some codes in here with b_queryset . . .
c_queryset = a_queryset.get(id=10)  # re-filtered
# some codes in here with c_queryset . . .

I have N+1 problem which is three SELECT queries and I already know these codes cause it.
It would be very nice to call queryset at once, but I can't because there're some tasks with using these querysets in the middle.
Is there any way to solve it? What should I do?

A queryset is an iterable, you can simply iterate over it and filter out the entries you want maybe using list comprehension (the result won't be a queryset though)? Note that what you describe isn't really the N + 1 problem though.

@AbdulAzizBarkat
If there is some process with a queryset in the middle, is the problem inevitable?

This is not an "N+1" problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/97253/15127.   You have three things to do, and run three queries to do it.  Without knowing the commented out details there isn't any help that we can give.

@Andrew oh I finally know that was not n+1 problem. I will re-ask my more question(with details) in another post. thank you.

It's a trade-off between running three DB queries, and retrieving all the data with one big query (then filtering it with Python). One has extra  DB server overhead, the other has data-bandwidth  and memory cost. Note queryset .values() and .values_list() can be used to fetch only the data from the objects that you actually need, to alleviate the latter.
